# How to convert JavaScript to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert the JavaScript code below to jQuery? I'm not a JavaScript or jQuery expert.

Here is the JavaScript code.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function( ev ) {
  var blockTags = ['div','h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','p','pre','li','blockquote','ul','ol',
  'table','thead','tbody','tfoot','td','th',];

  for (var i = 0; i < blockTags.length; i++)
  {
     ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( blockTags[i], {
        indent : false,
        breakBeforeOpen : true,
        breakAfterOpen : false,
        breakBeforeClose : false,
        breakAfterClose : true
     });
  }
});
```

Comment: Jquery is still Javascript so why change it? What do you want to archive?

Comment: Just for the heck of it, I Googled 'jquery for ckeditor'. I didn't look at any of the results, but it appears there are one or more jquery plugins for ckeditor.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't change this to JQuery as it has nothing to do with the DOM, DOM manipulation or DOM traversal.

It's only configuring the CKEditor, and JQuery can't help with that...

Answer (score 1):

You could put it in the JQuery $(document).ready() function without having to change the code at all

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function( ev ) {
      var blockTags = ['div','h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','p','pre','li','blockquote','ul','ol','table','thead','tbody','tfoot','td','th',];

      for (var i = 0; i < blockTags.length; i++)
      {
         ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( blockTags[i], {
            indent : false,
            breakBeforeOpen : true,
            breakAfterOpen : false,
            breakBeforeClose : false,
            breakAfterClose : true
         });
      }
    });
});
```

This will affect all instances of CKeditor if that is what you want.